# MS Access GUI macro for starting external program?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am having trouble finding information about the creation of an MS Access GUI Macro (VB) for starting an external program.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Shell()` function:

```
result = Shell("C:\My\Program\To\Run.exe")
```

See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/shell-function-HA001228906.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible to create a GUI button? - Or don't these macros support it, e.g.: I'll need to make an add-in?

Answer (score 1):

`WScript.Shell` offers another option:

```
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.Exec "CALC.EXE"
Set wshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: and  windows script is 64 bit?

Comment: @MitchWheat Apparently so, or at least it *can* be. `wshShell.Exec "EXCEL.EXE"` just launched 64-bit Excel from my 64-bit Access module.